# how to get the default version of AWS EKS clusters via aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-eks

I'm trying to create a script that compares the versions of my clusters with the current default version so I know when to upgrade the cluster's version.

e.g:

- my current cluster version is 1.26
- EKS DEFAULT_VERSION is 1.27

***( {my_version} doesn't equal DEFAULT_VERSION) ==> upgrade***

I get my cluster's version via this command:

```
aws eks describe-cluster --name <cluster_name> --region <my_region> --query "cluster.version"
```

Output:

```
"1.26"
```

Which command gets me the DEFAULT_VERSION?
Here's the Default from the AWS console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest eksctl [here](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/releases) and run `eksctl version -o json | jq -r '.EKSServerSupportedVersions[-1]'`. The command returned `1.27` to date.

Comment: this gives '1.23' as an output

Comment: Update your `eksctl` first then run the given command.

Comment: yup, you're right! problem is, this gives the latest supported version [-1]. not necessarily the DEFAULT

Comment: EKS default version is the latest version. Your screenshot is one way to verify that.

Comment: The community releases new Kubernetes minor versions, but they don't automatically immediately become the default version on EKS. So my screenshot shows the default after the LATEST (1.27) became the default.
Is there a way to verify that the latest is the default before running this command? I need the default and not always the latest

Comment: Note whether your current cluster version can be update to the latest version with just 1 update is a different question.